# How to detect mobile device in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to include indexmob.php if user come from mobile device. I also tried with

```
<?php
   if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
     include 'indexmob.php';
   }
   else
   {
     include 'indexpc.php';
   }

?>
```

but it only detecting mobile device , it showing only indexpc.php

What changes I should have to do with it ??

Answer (score 0):

There are few found.
[This is from github](http://codediesel.com/demos/test/mobile.php) [Mobile-detector](https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect)

UPDATE:
[Mobile detecting plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mobile-detect/)

Comment: is there wordpress support it in theme ??